# Почему alert("hi there") не работает внутри yii?

Tags: javascript, yii

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Всем привет в большом проекте нужно менять js код  но мои попытки подключить js все неудачны.Какие варианты я попробовал

1.Подключать через `AppAsset.php`

2.Подключать через `<script src="js/script.js">`

3.Подключать через `<script type="text/javascript">alert("hi there");`

никакой из этих вариантов не сработало прошу заметить что проект довольно большой сайт типо booking-a как правильно подключить и изменять js файлы в yii помогите пожалуйста.Во всех случаях я использовал простой скрипт назвал `script.js` в котором был метод `alert("hi there")`

Comment: В консоль смотрели? Возможно где-то ошибка js еще до вашего alert`а

Comment: @ДмитрийМатвиенко ошибкы нету предупреждение есть шас скриншот  добавлю в вопрос

Comment: Для начала стоит открыть исходный код страницы в браузере и проверить есть ли в ней код alert("hi there"). Если нет проблема в скриптах сервера, а если найдется значит где-то в яваскрипте. Если подключаете файлом нужно проверить правильный ли путь указан, доспен ли файл по прямой ссылке в браузере.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне помог такой вариант внизу `index.php` написать `$this->registerJs('alert("hi there");');` теперь можно спокойно писать код :)